# Did access section has effect on the size of bit filed in c++ data model?

Tags: c++

In my opinion, the access section (public/private/protected) in c++ should not have effect on c++ data model, so I have a test as below.

```
 #include <iostream>
 class A {
 private:
     long long int a:5;
     long long int b:3;
 };

 class B : public A {
 private:
     long long int c:5;
     long long int d:3;
 };

 class AA {
 public:
     long long int a:5;
     long long int b:3;
 };

 class BB : public AA {
 private:
     long long int c:5;
     long long int d:3;
 };

 int main(void) {
     std::cout << "A = " << sizeof(A) << " B = " << sizeof(B) << std::endl;
     std::cout << "AA = " << sizeof(AA) << " BB = " << sizeof(BB) << std::endl;
 }
```

Strange thing is the output results,
A = 8 B = 8
AA = 8 BB = 16

More information about the platform:
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)

Have anyone know the reason?

Comment: All this is implementation defined. We can't expect something specific. The compiler decided not to share public and private bits in the single underlying long long.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So public and private are not share the bits only when they are defined as bit filed.  Because I also have a test, when it is not defined as bit filed, public data in Derived class will store closely after the private data of Base classes .